# ogr2ogr update failing to update shapefile int PostGIS

Tags: gdal, error, ogr2ogr

I have a bunch of shapefiles that I am looping in with a bash script to load and update files but the ogr2ogr fails. I am running gdal 1.92 on ubuntu 14.04.

```
for file in `ls *.shp`;do ogr2ogr -progress -append -update -skipfailures -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -nlt MULTIPOLYGON -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=data_test" $file -sql "SELECT gid,name,id from ${file%.*}" -lco SCHEMA=test;done
```

> ERROR 1: Layer test.boundary already exists, CreateLayer failed.Use the layer creation option OVERWRITE=YES to replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be documented in http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html. Perhaps ogr2ogr do not undestand to append either.

> SCHEMA: Set name of schema for new table. Using the same layer name in
>   different schemas is supported, but not in the public schema and
>   others. Note that using the -overwrite option of ogr2ogr and -lco
>   SCHEMA= option at the same time will not work, as the ogr2ogr utility
>   will not understand that the existing layer must be destroyed in the
>   specified schema. Use the -nln option of ogr2ogr instead, or better
>   the active_schema connection string. See below example.

The active_schema example is on another page http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg_advanced.html

> This example shows how to convert a set of shapefiles inside the
>   apt200810 directory into an existing Postgres schema apt200810. In
>   that example, we could have use the schemas= option instead. (Starting
>   with GDAL 1.7.0)
>
> ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL "PG:dbname=warmerda active_schema=apt200810"
>   apt200810

Comment: redefining the postgis connection for a different schema did the trick. wonder why it doesn't work